# Calculated column with IF condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula, microsoft-lists

[image]I'm writing from Italy. I have a list of 5 columns: one of them is called "available" and it's a yes/no column.

Another column is a text column called "last name". I want to create a calculated column which takes last name ONLY if "available=yes" otherwise it should leave the field empty.

I tried `=IF([Available]="Yes","[Last Name]","")` but it doesn't work.

"syntax error" is the answer. What's wrong according to you?

Comment: Just want to confirm - Is it a yes/no (boolean) column or choice column with Yes and No choices?

Comment: it's a boolean column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `[Available]` is a Yes/No (Boolean) column, use formula like:

```
=IF([Available],[Last Name],"")
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (It is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Make sure you are using correct display name of columns in your formula (case sensitive).

Comment: For choice column with Yes and No choices, you have to use: `=IF([Available]="Yes",[Last Name],"")`

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work "Syntax error or not supported".i even tried =SE and ; (due i'm from italy) but it's not working.may be they should be activated somewhere ???

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of calculated column settings you are using while creating a column?

Comment: done in the main post

Comment: tks for any help

Comment: Not sure about language of your site. Can you create similar list in site with English language and check if this formula works: `=IF([Available]="Yes",[Last Name],"")`

Comment: i switched the site language in english,but it still doesn't work.i'm going mad

Comment: Correction in above comment, in case of Yes/No column you have to use: `=IF([Available],[Last Name],"")`

Comment: nothing works.perhaps formula should be activated somewhere ?

Comment: thanks anyway for your help

Comment: It works for me (see above screenshot). Can you try same in another SharePoint site in same tenant OR another tenant? If still doesn't work, raise support ticket with Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Comment: i tried with your suggestions with " =IF(REPERIBILE;NOMINATIVO;"") " and now it works.THANKSSSSSSS

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!